# How to load a static file in Flask app when deploying to Heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, static-files

I have a Flask JSON API application that would read a file in the code repository and display the data in that file. My application file is as follows:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

from utils import load_data


data = load_data(os.environ.get('DATA_FILE_PATH'))  # This would be in data/data.txt for example

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return jsonify(data=data)
```

When I deploy to Heroku, how can I set the environment variable to point to that particular data file? Locally, I would do

```
$ export DATA_FILE_PATH=/path/to/repo/data/data.txt
```

I know I can use the Heroku CLI `heroku config:set DATA_FILE_PATH=<path>` but I'm not sure how to place that path variable since I don't really know the directory structure on the Heroku deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add them in the settings tab config vars
[image: Heroku settings tab]

Comment: I'm aware of this, I mean how do I determine the value of the DATA_FILE_PATH without knowing the underlying filesystem structure?

Comment: The value of the DATA_FILE_PATH should be  ` /app/data/data.txt ` as @Syafiq mentioned but you don't need to know the underling structure to reference a file, you can just set it equal to ` data/data.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out you can go into the Heroku Dyno's `bash` using the following command (assuming you've already pushed to Heroku):

```
$ heroku run bash
```

and figure out what the file system structure looks like. In my particular case, my repo was served under the `/app` directory. So all I needed to pass into the value of the `DATA_FILE_PATH` environment variable is `/app/data/data.txt`.